# Remove all symbolic links of files in one command

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remove all the symbolic links of files. I have a directory structure like `/usr/local/instantclient/11.2.0.3` which contains lots of files and i have symbolic links of these files in `/usr/local/lib/` Now i want to delete all these symbolic links of those files. How can i do this in one command. If i remove the actual dir `/usr/local/instantclient/11.2.0.3` containing files then it will leave the broken links in `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To remove the links (from `man find` under `-type`):

```
          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
                 -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link  is
                 broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
                 is in effect, use -xtype.
```

I think this should do the trick:

```
find /usr/local/lib/ -maxdepth 1 -follow  -type l
```

Does the output produce a list of the files you want to delete? If so, when you are 100% sure:

```
find /usr/local/lib/ -maxdepth 1 -follow  -type l -delete
```

This will remove only broken links. To delete **all** links, remove the `-follow` stanza, but I wouldn't do that under `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Just to clarify: this assumes that the target directory has already been removed, so the links are already broken. The command will list _all_ broken symlinks in the `/usr/local/lib` directory (but not recurse), so if there are other broken links, then it will show more than needed. Not that there should be a lot of broken links there to begin with, so it's probably OK, but it is possible for a system to have purposefully broken links, and we'd like to spare those.

Comment: I tried the command suggested by Petter. The `-follow` option doesn't work. Only `find /usr/local/lib/ -maxdepth 1 -type l | delete` worked. But i think this is not the best way to do it. There is actually no way to list all the soft links of a file while hard links of a files can be listed using inode value of file. Here is a discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/linux-find-all-symlinks-of-a-given-original-file-reverse-readlink

Comment: How to find and delete all hard links to a file is discussed here http://linuxcommando.blogspot.in/2008/09/how-to-find-and-delete-all-hard-links.html  but this doesn't work for sybmolic links.

Comment: While there may be no (easy) way of "reverse readlink" a symbolic link, I don't see how that is relevant to your problem; you said that the links created were located in `/usr/local/lib`? 
also, do you have no `-follow` option in your version of find?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux this will do it.  Modify levels deep to suit you:

find /home/cc-000000025-com/domains -maxdepth 3 -type l -exec rm {} ;